# How to check for range of values in an Array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am wondering if this is possible in Perl without a `for` loop.

I have an array filled with numbers ranging from 1 to 7 (could be repeating).

I am sorting the array first. Then I get the lowest element.

What I need is, if the value of the first element is 1, then I want to check if the array contains (2,3,4,5).

Can I do this in one line, without a loop?

Comment: What happens if the first element is not 1? Why do you want to avoid a loop?

Comment: I got to update status on another system much complex which i didnt want to explain. If the value is > 1 then i do something else.

Comment: Am new to this, but was thinking... could you maybe print the @arr to a $string then maybe regex on that to find the pattern...

Comment: @Carpenter is right if the array contain ONLY NUMBERS BETWEEN 1 and 7. You can do something like: print "has 2,3,4,5" if join('', @arr) =~ m/2+3+4+5+/xmsi;

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan => you still have not explained why you do not want a loop?

Comment: I felt the loop will be time consuming. Thats the main reason. Now i have implemented with loop

Comment: @KarthikKrishnan => any time that you think a loop will be too time consuming, consider how the other solutions will be implemented behind the scenes.  Chances are that the other solution is just a loop hidden behind a subroutine call or two.  The simple fact of the matter is that if you have `n` elements, and you are only scanning the list once, you are not going to get better than `O(n)` performance.  Multiple scans might offer room for optimization.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why you sort array first but for checking of existence of some values in array you can use for example this approach:

```
sub check2345 {
  my %h;
  @h{@_}=();
  return 4 == grep exists $h{$_}, 2 .. 5;
}
```

if you rely on one line (expression):

```
do{my%h;@h{@array}=();4==grep exists$h{$_},2..5}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in one line by using a `grep`/`keys`/`map` construct:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @arr = ( 1, 2, 4, 5 );
say "has 2, 3, 4, 5" if 4 == grep { $_ == 2 || $_ == 3 || $_ == 4 || $_ == 5 } keys %{{ map { $_ => 1 } @arr }};
```

If your elements are going to be integers, you can shorten the `grep` to:

```
grep { $_ >= 2 && $_ <= 5 }
```

If you want to make things a little more supportable (i.e. if your end bounds might be changing), you could try:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @arr = ( 1, 2, 4, 5 );
my $first = 2;
my $last = 5;
say "has them all" if ($last-$first+1) == grep { $_ >= $first && $_ <= $last } keys %{{ map { $_ => 1 } @arr }};
```

(Note that in both of my examples the script should print nothing, since the array doesn't have all of the elements (2, 3, 4, 5)).

**Edit:** Based on Hynek's comment below, I've removed the useless use of `map` and allowed for duplicate values in the original array.

Comment: You map usage is useless and both your solutions don't solve duplicates which are explicitly stated in question.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: I've edited my post to reflect your comments.